# How to virtualize windows already installed on the hard disk in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have a hd with windows and Ubuntu installed in dual boot, I'm wanting to virtualize the installation of windows in ubuntu. Is it possible?

Comment: With [Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) you can clone the windows hard drive content to a VHD file that can be imported into VirtualBox

Comment: humm, But when I make changes to the windows they will have no effect on vhd drive.

Comment: I use win 8.1 and ubuntu 14

Answer (score 0):

Use a disk cloning tool like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) and image the Windows partition.  Then restore the image to a virtual machine. You are probably using GRUB as the boot loader, you can to use the Windows Repair boot option from the Windows DVD to fix the boot record for Windows.

Comment: But when I make changes to the windows they will have no effect on vhd drive. So everytime i will have to image the the Windows partition when I modified, or not?